# How to distinguish "chance" from simulation events?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, standard-model, probability

People often like to think that given a certain probability of a dataset explaining results, like say 90%, then it implies if you "reran" events 10 times, 9 times they would return the same outcome.

From a classical view this is not the correct interpretation since the results leading up to the event in question have already been determined, so "rerunning" the same simulation should have no effect on the outcome. However, I don't know if that distinction has a name or exactly how to explain it or how to distinguish it from the intrinsic randomness implied by the standard model.

Chaotic behavior is not mutually exclusive with determinism, but the standard model doesn't prove intrinsic randomness one way or the other, but entropy and intrinsic randomness should also break time symmetry which means the results going backwards in time are not necessarily per-determined.

Answer (score 1):

In a deterministic scenario, assigning a probability to an outcome only makes sense if the initial conditions are allowed to vary (with some known distribution) or if there is some uncertainty in the initial conditions.

For example, it only makes sense to say that the top card of a deck of cards is a spade with probability $1$ in $4$ *if* the deck is randomly ordered, or if we do not know the order of the deck. But if the deck has a fixed and known order then the top card either is or is not a spade - there is no probability involved here.

Comment: I don't think you understand the issue here. The issue here is that fundamentally, we never knew whether initial conditions were allowed to vary at all or whether the universe is deterministic.

Comment: @JRRs Everything in classical physics is deterministic. Even in quantum physics the evolution of each wave function is deterministic, and the only stochastic events are collapse of wave functions (which are not objective events in some interpretations). Even in a deterministic scenario a statement about probabilities of outcomes is still legitimate as it can reflect our partial knowledge about initial conditions - this is the basis of Bayesian statistics. But another editor may provide an answer that is more in line with your expectations.

Comment: Right, classical physics is deterministic. We don't know with 100% certainty that wave functions are deterministic, only that based on the current statistical evidence that given 26 parameters, one may attempt to predict the future state of a particle to some correlation. It's not really my expectations, it's what is currently known. Maybe another university can provide you with information more in line with your level of understanding.